# Ionic full screen background image

Tags: css, ionic-framework

I am new to the Ionic framework and I am trying to start the app with a full screen background image like this:

[image]

I did manage to remove the statusbar it was shown in the tutorial. But how do I add a full screen image? When I added this to the style.css it didn't react:

```
html, body{
  background-image: black;
}
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In your css, try:

```
  .scroll-content {
    background: url(image) [add image position info here];

    [add any more properties here]

  }
```

This will set the background for the full content area.

Comment: This works but not for the nav-bar which I have hide-nav-bar="true" on. I actually want to completely remove this.

Answer (score 16):

in

```
ion-view class="pane"
```

all the stuff is rendered ... i did not try it out but i think you can manage this with

```
    .pane {
        background: url(image) no-repeat center center fixed; 
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
    }
```

Answer (score 9):

Make sure the start of your image path has "../" this will point it to the correct image path in your resource folder once the app is built for a device. Using the pane method only seemed to cause problems this was the best solution for me when the image was appearing when served but not on my android device.

```
.scroll-content{
    background: url("../media/images/background.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;

}
```

Answer (score 7):

Very similar to answer from Helmut, which worked using 'ionic serve' but gave me a white background when I pushed to Android (4.2.2 on a Nexus 7 in my case).

The pane class selector is correct if you wish to make the background fullscreen, however android just seemed to make the background white if I set the "background" value at all. Using "background-image" put things right.

I found the following worked on Android, and in Chrome (while web testing).

```
.pane {
    background-image: url(image); 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

In Ioinc-5:
Create a in class home-page.scss.

```
.class-name {
  --background: url("/assets/icon/background.jpg") 0 0/100% 100% no-repeat
 }
```

Open home-page.html and add class in ion-content.

```
<ion-content class="class-name">
```

Answer (score 4):

Since the folder structures have changed recently in Ionic 2 beta...

Your image should be at a path similar to `www/img/backgrounds/lake.png`, and the accompanying CSS should read:

```
.myClassName {
    background: url(../../img/backgrounds/lake.png) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Note: you need to jump up 2 directories, `../../`

Answer (score 4):

**Ionic 4 Change Background color of Ion Content**

[image]

Explained here [**Source Link**](https://www.freakyjolly.com/ionic-3-4-how-to-change-css-custom-properties-of-ui-components/#ionic4ImageBackroundOnPage)

```
ion-content{
--background: url(./assets/images/bg1.jpg);
--background-repeat: no-repeat;
--background-size: cover;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code to change your image url with full background with different device.

```
  ion-content {
    --background: none;
    background-image: url('https://cdn.wallpapersafari.com/19/81/zOUft6.jpg');
    background-position: center top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

below code works for me

```
--background: none;
  background-image: url('../../../assets/imgs/splash.png') ;
  background-position: center top;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
```